# Using custom LibGDX with gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle, libgdx

I was looking at this question

http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17140

And it suggested to use mvn install in the LibGDX directory. I did that but LibGDX doesn't install into the local repository, it installs in some extensions folder. So when I use mavenLocal() in my build.gradle, it doesn't catch my version.

I'm guessing that there's a new way of doing it since that link is pretty old?

Also, in the link it mentions something about how the newest version always gets used if it has the same version number, how do I make it so gradle only uses my version of LibGDX?